# Address field or depenent taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

I need an address field to filter nodes with depenent selectors or autocomleted inputs. There is no needs to have any database of countries, regions, cities. It is enought if admin will able to add ones manually. But it is required to have simple dep.selectors in widgets while setting values or filtering.

I tried https://www.drupal.org/project/address but there is no selector for the city subfield. May be it is possible to show selector here based on existing values?

Also, I tried to create several taxonomies (country, region, city) with custom fields(region have country reference, city - region and country refs), but I do not know how to link them really at input widgets, so I can select country and cities selector will show only this country cities, or I when selected city, the country selected automatically, based on its refs.

Thank you!